# Tomcat : Restrict java web service from accessing host machine file system

Tags: web-services, windows-7, spring-security, tomcat7, security

I have web service written in java (war file) (Using Spring Security) . In web service, I can read all files over host machine(Using FileInputStream).

My host machine (Windows system) contains very sensitive data that I don't want to share with anyone.

Suppose somebody gets access to my tomcat unauthentically(in any way), then he can deploy files on it & can run commands on it, with which he can easily get access to my host machine file system.

How this can be prevented ?

I can disable auto deploy & do other security tricks on tomcat to prevent attacks.

But, this won't solve my problem.

Is this make sense that my file system is unsecured & it's a thing to worry about.
Or better I should not keep sensitive data on server.

Comment: **Is this make sense that my file system is unsecured & it's a thing to worry about. Or better I should not keep sensitive data on server.** *Yes, be very worried and don't keep sensitive data within arm's reach*. **In web service, I can read all files over host machine(Using FileInputStream).** You're begging to be breached

Comment: But, Can I block some directories from tomcat access. Like some folders on D Drive ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several answers to this. First off: consider running the tomcat on a seperate machine that does not contain sensitive data. Other than that, you should ensure that the user or service that is used to run tomcat has minimal system rights. It does not need to be able to access the entire file system.

A bunch of security considerations and tips is available at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html.

Further more you might consider running tomcat with a security manager that is used to restrict the priviliges of the executed java code. Have a look at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html to see how tomcat can be setup to use a security manager.